# How to create a dynamic dropown using angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create some dynamic dropdown menus in the navbar. I have the informations in a javascript object. want to use those data to create the dropdown menus. For example:

let's say I have a javascript object like this:

```
Food = 
[
  {
    Name : "Fruits",
    Item : 
    { 
      1 : "Apple", 
      2 : "Banana"}
    },
    {
     Name : "Drinks",
     Item : 
     {
        1 : "Milk",
        2 : "Tea"
     }
   }
]
```

Want to produce something like this

```html
<ul>
  <li>Fruit
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Drink
    <ul>
      <li> Milk </li>
      <li> Tea </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Need help here:

```
<ul *ngFor = "let f of Food">
    <li>{{f}}
         <ul *ngFor = "let i of Food.Item>
              <li>{{what to put here?}}</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your JSON is not valid. If you want to make this as a valid JSON, it should be like

> [   {
>       "Name": "Fruits",
>       "Item": {
>         "1": "Apple",
>         "2": "Banana"
>       }   },   {
>       "Name": "Drinks",
>       "Item": {
>         "1": "Milk",
>         "2": "Tea"
>       }   } ]

What you have is an array of Objects, not array of arrays.so you need to access objects using fieldname as follows,

```
<ul *ngFor = "let f of Food">
    <li>{{f.Name}}
         <ul>
              <li>{{f.Item[1]}}</li>
               <li>{{f.Item[2]}}</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3aavh?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks! But what if I have three item in fruits and two item in drinks? I do not want to hard code it like `{{f.Item[1]}}`. This is the major issue.

Comment: in that case you need to have an array and use nested ngFor

Comment: it would be very useful if you can demonstrate it with an example.

Comment: something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3aavh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html